# Is it possible to change the Sql Workflow Persistence Service table and stored procedure names?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, sqlworkflowpersistencese

I'm using the default Sql Workflow Persistence Service to manage workflow persistence in an application I'm developing. I used the scripts provided by Microsoft to generate the schema and logic in a SQL database. Up until now, it's worked great; however, I'd like to change the names of both the tables and stored procedures to comply with a naming convention of my choosing.

For example, the script provided by Microsoft generated a stored procedure named `RetrieveNonblockingInstanceStateIds` and I'd like to change it's name to `wf_RetrieveNonblockingInstanceStateIds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably create your own persistence service, but personally I'd leave it well alone as it is.

Comment: Yeah... I ended up deciding it wasn't worth the hassle. I found no way of doing it without creating my own persistence service provider, and it's really not worth it, just to rename some tables and stp's :)